# Is there a way to SUMIFS with multiple criteria + true or false?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I want to sum the total value with its correct corresponding criteria and if the last condition will be true or false. If true, it will proceed to the sumifs, and if false "0" value. If there is no date, the value in each column will be zero

```
D9=SUMIFS(STORE!$C$6:$C$1000;STORE!$A$6:$A$1000;"*"&SUMMARY!$D$5&"*";STORE!$D$6:$D$1000;"*"&SUMMARY!$C$9&"*";STORE!$E$6:$E$1000;"*"&SUMMARY!D8&"*")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't so clear. Where are the criteria column or conditions in your excel? According to your current formula, if there is no date, all values should be zero. why are you using "*"& &"*"?

As I understood maybe you can add as the last criteria

=SUMIFS(STORE!$C$6:$C$1000;STORE!$A$6:$A$1000;""&SUMMARY!$D$5&"";STORE!$D$6:$D$1000;""&SUMMARY!$C$9&"";STORE!$E$6:$E$1000;""&SUMMARY!D8&"";**STORE!$AA$6:$AA$1000;TRUE**)

STORE!$AA$6:$AA$1000: False or True column